# Cell ID info on iPhone with Flex 4.5 SDK

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, flex4.5

Is it possible to get Cell ID and LAC on iPhone using Flex 4.5 SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Not right now, at least.  That level of OS integration is not available in Flex Mobile.  If you need that information, you will need to go native.

It has been said that we will see "native extensions" in Air that will allow us to get access to things like this, but there is no word to when this will actually happen:

http://active.tutsplus.com/articles/news/industry-news-week-22-2011/

Comment: Thank you @Brian Genisio for the information. Hope we'll see those native extensions soon.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not exposed natively in Mobile AIR today, you can do some work arounds to make it work.  Take a look at this post on extending AIR for Android:

http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/

I assume the same approach could be applied on an iOS device, although I would not bank on the fact that Apple would approve an application that did so.

Comment: Ha!  Good luck with that.  Some major hacking going on there.  Not to slight James Ward in any way... it is just that he is a genius hacker and if you are not him, you probably won't get it working :)